# How to use Mac printer driver in ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

### Update/Solved

> Eventually I can print with Canon G1000 in my Ubuntu with help of
>   Turboprint driver. For more information, read [their release](http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Canon_PIXMA_G1000series).

---

thanks for reading!

Just bought a [Canon G1000](http://www.canon.co.id/personal/products/inkjet-printers/inkjet-single-function/pixma-g1000?languageCode=EN), but there's no Linux support yet. I have mailed them and the answer is no Linux driver at the time.

I'm a linux user for years, but I'm really new to CUPS (never had to struggle with a printer until this one!).

1- Since the Mac OS X drivers are [available](http://search-id.canon-asia.com/canon__id_en__id_p_en/search.x?ct=Support&hf=category%09zubaken&cf=model_sm:PIXMA%20G1000&d=DOWNLOADS), I was wondering if I could extract the PPD from it to feed my Ubuntu? I have xar the dmg file, but couln't find any PPD from it.

2- If possible, how to use files extracted from DMG file to be used as Linux driver?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to extract the PPD file from the OSX cups drivers. Since I don't know whether I can post it for license reasons, here are the steps to reproduce.

I haven't managed to get the printer to work yet however, but I'm posting this with the hope that someone might be able to solve the remaining bits of problems.

- download OSX CUPS driver from Canon site: http://support-id.canon-asia.com/contents/ID/EN/0100700802.html
- `7z x mcpd-mac-g1000-13_13_0_0-ea21_3.dmg` (or whatever the file you got is called)
- `7z x "2 - disk image(Apple_HFS：2)"` which was extracted from original `.dmg` file
- `cd "PrinterDriver_G1000 series/"`
- `7z x "PrinterDriver_G1000 series_131300.pkg"` which gives you a `G1000.pkg` folder among other files
- `cd G1000.pkg`
- `zcat Scripts | cpio -i`
- `cd CIJModules`
- `tar xzf CanonIJPPD.tgz` gives you `CanonIJG1000series.ppd.gz` which is the PPD you want. It still needs editing as it includes a number of lines pointing to OSX paths ("`/Library/...`")

I am still trying to figure out what is wrong with my setup, but at least you can work on the PPD now :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is about using the Mac driver of Canon G1000 as a source of driver for this printer in Ubuntu. My answer is not exactly regarding that. But I assume that what the poster wanted is to have a completely working driver for Linux. My answer addresses this:

The options for a person trying to install Canon's G1000 and G2000 are limited to the following:

1. **Compile and install gutenprint (Recommended)**. Gutenprint, formerly named Gimp-Print, is a suite of printer drivers for linux. It works just like native drivers and supports cups based printing. It is completely **free**.
2. **Buy a third party linux printing driver and utility, called [Turboprint](http://www.turboprint.info/download.html)**. It too has excellent support. An added bonus is a GUI for checking printer spooling, and configuring varied options like Paper type, resolution etc. The cost of an individual license is upwards of $34.

If you decide to go with the first solution, the steps include the following. My system is a Ubuntu Xenial 64bit.

First you need some developmental headers. So add to your sources.list the following lines if you dont have them. Modify these according to your version of Linux(Debian/Ubuntu):

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update your sources and install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now download the source release package for gutenberg (version >=5.2.13) from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/).

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/gutenprint-5.2.13.tar.bz2/download
tar xvf download
cd gutenprint-5.2.13
```

Alternately clone the git repo.

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gimp-print/source gimp-print-source
cd gimp-print-source
```

Now configure, make and install.

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Source: [My blog post](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, many many thanks droidzone!  printer canon G1500.

I have 64bit Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS xenial with xcfe xubuntu

I try to add some details for people not competent like myself... and in case they have problems (like in my case) with the source.list  (forgive my English, I am Italian)

We are trying to install the drivers of the printer.
we want to add 2 web addresses from which download the drivers.
one way is to open the window "software and updates"
tab "software for ubuntu" activate option "source code"
then tab "Other software", press "add"
paste:

deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

then

deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

close "software and updates"

we open a terminal and give the command  " sudo apt update " - maybe will ask to restart and we can then restart the computer...

command " sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev "

if, as happened to me, the answer is like " Reading package list ... Done
E: It is necessary to insert some "source" URIs in the sources.list file "
it means that it does not have an address from which download the programs you can go to point 2. bellow ;

if every thing went fine (no answers) then go to the answer from Droidzone at step: sudo apt-get install build-essential

2.
we should check the file  sources.list in   /etc/apt/
we open sources.list in   /etc/apt/

if in front of the addresses starting with  "deb-src http://... there is the character # in my case solved getting rid of the character  #

to edit the file  sources.list (make copy of the file sources.list and paste in the desktop) in the terminal you can write the the command: " sudo mousepad /etc/apt/sources.list " (mousepad is a text editor, but you can use gedit or others...)

once opened cancel the characters # in front of the addresses starting as "deb-src http://... then save the file

now you can try again with command "sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev"

then go to the answer from Droidzone at step: sudo apt-get install build-essential