# Porting a PPD to Linux from OSX-filter error?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Since my printer Canon Pixma G1000 doesnt seem to be supported by Canon for a Linux driver, I have attempted to port the PPD from OSX to Linux. My early attempts are [here](https://github.com/droidzone/canong1000). The printer does not print.

To port this driver, the steps I did include extracting the PPD file from the Mac OSX .dng file, removing osx specific entries including `Attribute "APPrinterPreset"`. I changed filters from MacOSX versions to rastertocanonij and cmdtocanonij2 after compiling and installing these filters from the c[nijfilter2 source](https://github.com/dbnicholson/cnijfilter2). I then made the .drv file and "compiled" a fresh ppd.

Unfortunately the error message that cups shows is "filter does not work". On setting the loglevel of cups at debug, I found the following errors:

```
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] 4 filters for job:
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
I [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 26026)
I [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 26027)
I [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 26028)
I [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertocanonij (PID 26029)
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] PID 26029 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertocanonij) stopped with status 255 (Unknown error 155)
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] PID 26026 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) exited with no errors.
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] PID 26027 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] PID 26028 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
E [24/Apr/2017:23:22:40 +0530] [Job 38] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:42 +0530] [CGI] envp[9] = "PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [24/Apr/2017:23:22:42 +0530] [CGI] cgiSetArray: job_printer_state_message[0]=\"Filter failed\"
```

There were no compiler errors during make of the cups filters. I'm not sure where the error is in the filters, or whether this printer is incompatible with these filters, or whether there is an issue in the ppd file.

How would I proceed to get my printer working in Ubuntu? Please dont comment asking me to request Canon to support it. I've already contacted them through Support and twitter. They dont seem inclined to.

Comment: You should ask this person: https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz Back when I had a canon he was the one that made it work.

Comment: I've already emailed him.

Comment: Cool. But the last-build on both ppa scares me. Looks like he stopped :(

Comment: for completeness, Turboprint now offer a printer driver for several of Canon's G series printer; for the G1000 here this link http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Canon_PIXMA_G1000series shows the support. Turboprint offer very good printer drivers; a free and a contributed version;

Comment: Well.. what do you know? It was heart warming to see the printer work in Turboprint. Thanks a lot! Though it would have been awesome to be able to DIY and fix the printer to work with cnijfilter or to have native support with Canon driver, I'll probably buy Turboprint to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question since I recently found the solution to the conundrum arising from Canon being reluctant to provide native Linux drivers. I asked how to port drivers from OSX because there were no native drivers available.

The options for a person trying to install Canon's G1000 and G2000 are limited to the following:

1. Compile and install gutenprint. Gutenprint, formerly named Gimp-Print, is a suite of printer drivers for linux. It works just like native drivers and supports cups based printing.
2. Buy a third party linux printing driver and utility, called Turboprint. It too has excellent support. An added bonus is a GUI for checking printer spooling, and configuring varied options like Paper type, resolution etc. The cost of an individual license is upwards of $34.

If you decide to go with the first solution, the steps include the following. My system is a Ubuntu Xenial 64bit.

First you need some developmental headers. So add to your sources.list the following lines if you dont have them. Modify these according to your version of Linux(Debian/Ubuntu):

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update your sources and install the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get build-dep cups-common gimp-gutenprint libgutenprint-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now download the source release package for gutenberg (version >=5.2.13) from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/).

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.2/5.2.13/gutenprint-5.2.13.tar.bz2/download
tar xvf download
cd gutenprint-5.2.13
```

Alternately clone the git repo.

```
git clone https://git.code.sf.net/p/gimp-print/source gimp-print-source
cd gimp-print-source
```

Now configure, make and install.

```
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Source: [My blog post](http://blog.droidzone.in/2017/08/07/how-to-install-printers-for-canon-pixma-g2000-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

Turboprint release their support to Canon G1000 last April 2017. I have updated [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820280/how-to-use-mac-printer-driver-in-ubuntu) also.

Comment: My question was on trying to port the PPD to Linux. Turboprint works fine if one doesn't mind paying a fourth of the printer cost to third party. But Linux should be having drivers.